# Bash Multiple cURL request Issue

Tags: bash, curl, gnu-parallel

The script submits the files and Post submit , The API service returns "task_id" of the submitted samples ( `#task.csv` )

```
#file_submitter.sh

#!/bin/bash

for i in $(find $1  -type f);do
        task_id="$(curl -s -F file=@$i http://X.X.X.X:8080/api/abc/v1/upload &)"
        echo "$task_id" >> task.csv
done
```

Run Method :

```
$./submitter.sh /home/files/
```

Results : ( Here 761 & 762 is the task_id of the submitted sample from the API service )

```
#task.csv

{"task_url": "http://X.X.X.X:8080/api/abc/v1/task/761"}
{"task_url": "http://X.X.X.X:8080/api/abc/v1/task/762"}
```

I'm giving the entire folder path (`find $1  -type f`) to find all the files in the directory to upload the files. Now , I'm using "&" operator to submit/upload the files from the folder which will generate 'task_id' from the API service(stdout) and i wanted that `'task_id'`(stdout) to store it in `'task.csv'`. But the time taken to upload a file with `"&"` and without `"&"` is same. Is there any more method to do the submission parallel/faster? Any suggestions please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `xargs` with `-P` option:

```
find "$1" -type f -print0 |
xargs -0 -P 5 -I{} curl -s -F file='@{}' http://X.X.X.X:8080/api/abc/v1/upload >> task.csv
```

This will reduce total execution time by launching 5 `curl` process in parallel.

Comment: Using xargs , When i give the path './submitter.sh /home/files/pdf/' , It returns only one result . Let's say if the folder pdf has 5 files , The out result has to be around 5 task_ids right ?

Answer (score 2):

anubhava suggests using `xargs` with `-P` option:

```
find "$1" -type f -print0 |
xargs -0 -P 5  curl -s -F file=@- http://X.X.X.X:8080/api/abc/v1/upload >> task.csv
```

However, appending to the same file in parallel is generally a bad idea: You really need to know a lot about how this version of the OS buffers output for that to be safe. This example shows why:

```
#!/bin/bash

size=3000

myfile=/tmp/myfile$$
rm $myfile

echo {a..z} | xargs -P26 -n1 perl -e 'print ((shift)x'$size')' >> $myfile

cat $myfile | perl -ne 'for(split//,$_){
  if($_ eq $l) {
    $c++
  } else {
    /\n/ and next;
    print $l,1+$c," "; $l=$_; $c=0;
  }
}'
echo
```

With `size=10` you will always get (order may differ):

```
1 d10 i10 c10 n10 h10 x10 l10 b10 u10 w10 t10 o10 y10 z10 p10 j10 q10 s10 v10 r10 k10 e10 m10 f10 g10
```

Which means that the file contains 10 d's followed by 10 i's followed by 10 c's and so on. I.e. no mixing of the output from the 26 jobs.

But change it to `size=30000` and you get something like:

```
1 c30000 d30000 l8192 g8192 t8192 g8192 t8192 g8192 t8192 g5424 t5424 a8192 i16384 s8192 i8192 s8192 i5424 s13616 f16384 k24576 p24576 n8192 l8192 n8192 l13616 n13616 r16384 u8192 r8192 u8192 r5424 u8192 o16384 b8192 j8192 b8192 j8192 b8192 j8192 b5424 a21808 v8192 o8192 v8192 o5424 v13616 j5424 u5424 h16384 p5424 h13616 x8192 m8192 k5424 m8192 q8192 f8192 m8192 f5424 m5424 q21808 x21808 y30000 e30000 w30000
```

First 30K c's, then 30K d's, then 8k l's, then 8K g's, 8K t's, then another 8k g's, and so on. I.e. the 26 outputs were mixed together. Very non-good.

For that reason I will advice against appending to the same file in parallel: There is a risk of race condition, and it can often be avoided.

In your case you can simply use GNU Parallel instead of xargs, because GNU Parallel guards against this race condition:

```
find "$1" -type f -print0 |
parallel -0 -P 5  curl -s -F file=@{} http://X.X.X.X:8080/api/abc/v1/upload >> task.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

The command inside command substitution, `$()`, runs in a subshell; so here you are sending the `curl` command in the background of that subshell, not the parent shell.

Get rid of the command substitution, and Just do:

```
curl -s -F file=@$i http://X.X.X.X:8080/api/abc/v1/upload >task.csv &
```

Comment: To store the task_id of the process launched, `echo "$!" >> task.cv` after the `curl` command.

Answer (score 1):

You're telling the shell to parallelize inside of a command substitution (`$()`). That's not going to do what you want. Try this instead:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $(find $1  -type f);do
        curl -s -F file=@$i http://X.X.X.X:8080/api/abc/v1/upload &
done > task.csv
#uncomment next line if you want the script to pause until the last curl is done
#wait
```

This puts the `curl` into the background and saves its output into `task.csv`.

Comment: Thanks Eric. The 'task_id' is not the task/process ( echo $!) of the machine . This is auto-generated by the API service when a sample is submitted. Updated the question

Comment: Works perfect. How much process does it launch when using (&) ampersand. Because on the out result , I gotta see so many error message. due to the number of request i send at once . Can we limit the query that we send ?

Comment: For that, you may be able to use `xargs`:  e.g. `find "$1"  -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 -I % -P 5 curl -s -F 'file=%'  http://X.X.X.X:8080/api/abc/v1/upload > task.csv` will run 5 simultaneous curls. If you need real rate limiting, write a script that calls curl then `sleep`s.